# Get cumulative sum Pandas conditional on other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to create a column that shows the cumulative count (rolling sum) of previous purchases (per customer) that took place in department 99

My data frame looks like this ; where each row is a separate transaction.

```
    id  chain   dept    category    company     brand   date    productsize     productmeasure  purchasequantity    purchaseamount  sale
0   86246   205     7   707     1078778070  12564   2012-03-02  12.00   OZ  1   7.59    268.90
1   86246   205     63  6319    107654575   17876   2012-03-02  64.00   OZ  1   1.59    268.90
2   86246   205     97  9753    1022027929  0   2012-03-02  1.00    CT  1   5.99    268.90
3   86246   205     25  2509    107996777   31373   2012-03-02  16.00   OZ  1   1.99    268.90
4   86246   205     55  5555    107684070   32094   2012-03-02  16.00   OZ  2   10.38   268.90
5   86246   205     97  9753    1021015020  0   2012-03-02  1.00    CT  1   7.80    268.90
6   86246   205     99  9909    104538848   15343   2012-03-02  16.00   OZ  1   2.49    268.90
7   86246   205     59  5907    102900020   2012    2012-03-02  16.00   OZ  1   1.39    268.90
8   86246   205     9   921     101128414   9209    2012-03-02  4.00    OZ  2   1.50    268.90
```

I did this :

```
shopdata6['transactions_99'] = 0
shopdata6['transactions_99'] = shopdata6[shopdata6['dept'] == 99].groupby(['id', 'dept'])['transaction_99'].cumsum()
```

Update :

```
id dept  date   purchase purchase_count_dept99(desired)

id1 199  date1  $10       0    

id1 99  date1  $10       1

id1 100 date1  $50       1

id1 99  date2  $30       2

id2 100 date1  $10       0

id2 99  date1  $10       1

id3 99 date3  $10        1
```

Applied this :

```
shopdata6['transaction_99'] = np.where(shopdata6['dept']==99, 1, 0)
shopdata6['transaction_99'] = shopdata6.groupby(['id'])['transaction_99'].transform('cumsum')
```

The result does look okay, but is it correct ?

Comment: what is the expected df? can you please post that too? thanks(also exclude columns which are not relevant)

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: your samples contains only one row with dept 99, why do you show expected output has 4?

Comment: that is just a snippet of the entire df, whole data is 110k rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shopdata6['transaction_99'] = np.where(shopdata6['dept']==99, 1, 0)
shopdata6['transaction_99'] = shopdata6.groupby(['id'])['transaction_99'].transform('cumsum')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be simplify:

```
s = (shopdata6['dept']==99).astype(int)
shopdata6['transaction_99'] = s.groupby(shopdata6['id']).cumsum()
print (shopdata6)
    id  dept   date purchase  purchase_count_dept99(desired)  transaction_99
0  id1   199  date1      $10                               0               0
1  id1    99  date1      $10                               1               1
2  id1   100  date1      $50                               1               1
3  id1    99  date2      $30                               2               2
4  id2   100  date1      $10                               0               0
5  id2    99  date1      $10                               1               1
6  id3    99  date3      $10                               1               1
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly your problem, you need [.cumcount()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df["transaction_99"] = df[df["dept"] == 99].groupby("id").cumcount()
```

To make the count start from 1, just add this.

```
df["transaction_99"] = df["transaction_99"] + 1
```